# My electron app with create-react-app gives error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, create-react-app, react-scripts

When I'm working on my project the my electron window gives this error.

```
TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function
getElectronPath
../node_modules/electron/index.js:7
   4 | var pathFile = path.join(__dirname, 'path.txt')
   5 | 
   6 | function getElectronPath () {
>  7 |   if (fs.existsSync(pathFile)) {
   8 |     var executablePath = fs.readFileSync(pathFile, 'utf-8')
   9 |     if (process.env.ELECTRON_OVERRIDE_DIST_PATH) {
  10 |       return path.join(process.env.ELECTRON_OVERRIDE_DIST_PATH, executablePath)
```

What should I do?

I used this to create my project.

https://medium.com/@johndyer24/building-a-production-electron-create-react-app-application-with-shared-code-using-electron-builder-c1f70f0e2649

Comment: Did you include the 'preload.js' mentioned in the article?

Comment: yes.here is my preload.js

Comment: const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
window.ipcRenderer = ipcRenderer

Answer (score 0):

So I could solve this issue with me & my friend; We reversed my components to earlier version and the problem I saw should be that I used many fetch data operations inside useEffect method.

Comment: And I think I used the useEffect hook in a way I don't supposed to use.